# How to get the related field value of item in the queryset inside for loop

Tags: django, django-queryset

Supposed that we have a model `Patient` and `Diagnosis`.

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient, 
        related_name='diagnoses', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

In my views.py i was able to filter Patient whose diagnosis `is_active=True` with this code.

```
# returns queryset whose patient has active diagnosis.
queryset = Patient.objects.filter(
    diagnoses__is_active = True
)
```

But i cannot get the value using for loop with this. I added comment with the errors im getting.

```
for qs in queryset:
    # 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'is_active'
    print qs.diagnoses.is_active 

    # 'Patient' object has no attribute 'diagnoses__is_active'
    print qs.diagnoses__is_active

    # There is no error from this code but 
    # i got the 'diagnoses.Diagnoses.None' in return
    print qs.diagnoses
```

**How can it possibly be when i was able to filter the queryset in the first place?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Patient object will have a collection of Diagnosis objects associated with it.

When you do `for qs in queryset:`, `qs` becomes a Patient.

And then, `qs.diagnoses` is a `RelatedManager` that can be used to retrieve all the associated Diagnosis objects, but you need to do:

`qs.diagnoses.all()`

Or maybe

`qs.diagnoses.filter(is_active=True)` if you are only interested in the actives ones.

Comment: Thanks for this! it really works you saved my time here sir

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful. Don't forget to choose an accepted answer =)

Answer (score 1):

Because each `qs` has many diagnoses, ie, `qs.diagnoses` it's a new queryset. You need to use a iterate do get the diagnoses . Try this:

```
for diagnose in qs.diagnoses.all():
    print diagnose.is_active
```